# How to input values after for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have to make a program which inputs 10 student's grades and displays their weighed and unweighted averages. I am new to C++ programming so I don't know much and my professor doesn't like it when people use things he hasn't taught.

Here's the code: It shows up as What are the four test scores of student 1,2, etc. How can I make it to be when it says "What are the four test scores of student 1", then I would be able to enter those in. And then on to student2, student3, etc?

Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int numberofstudents = 10;

int main()
{

int student;
for(student=1; student<=numberofstudents; student++)
cout << "\nWhat are the four test scores of student number " << student << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In view of your comment, what have you covered so far?

Comment: You should be able to do this on your own.  I expect you've got some kind of documentation from your course.  If not, use google to find a C++ reference or tutorial.  Then, think!  You'll need some variable(s?) to store the data, you'll want to replace the one-line `for` body with a block (i.e., add `{` and `}`), and then put your computation in there.  You may need to add a second for loop inside the first one, depending on your way of solving this.

Comment: Tell your professor to stop doing this: `using namespace std;`

Comment: We've barely covered for loops, global variables, and cin and cout.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to read four values for each students, if so , then understand this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int numberofstudents = 10;
   double scores[numberofstudents][4];
   for(int student=0; student<numberofstudents; student++)
   {
     cout << "\nWhat are the four test scores of student number " << (student+1) << endl;
     int i = 0;
     while ( i < 4 )
     {
         //scores is a two dimentional array
         //scores first index is student number (starting with 0)
         //and second index is ith score  
         cin >> scores[student][i]; //read score, one at a time!
         i++;
     }
   }
   //process scores...
}
```

Now since it's your homework,  do the rest of your work yourself. All the best!